# Regex for matching the argument of a tex macro

Tags: regular-expression

Using the regex `\\todo{.\{-}}` I am able to match `\todo{stuff}`

But what I want to match is `{stuff}` whenever `\todo` immediately precedes it. Basically I do not want to include `\todo` in the matched part.

Can somebody please share what is the regex that would achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `\zs` atom [`:h /\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5czs):

```
\zs Matches at any position, and sets the start of the match there: The
    next char is the first char of the whole match. |/zero-width|
    Example:
        /^\s*\zsif
    matches an "if" at the start of a line, ignoring white space.
```

So your pattern should be

```
\\todo\zs{.\{-}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Just a note that if this is for syntax highlighting you’ll want to use one of the \@ forms instead of \zs